# How to create variables based on the length of the array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

So I'm trying to solve system of linear equations using **Cramer's Rule** and the main issue I'm facing is that I've to create **Ax,Ay,...An** variables everytime based on the dimension of the matrix. Is there any way in Python by which program can automatically create the variables based on the `for` loop initiated for dimension of the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a python solution (and for almost any other language) here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule

```
from numpy import linalg
 
A=[[2,-1,5,1],[3,2,2,-6],[1,3,3,-1],[5,-2,-3,3]]
B=[-3,-32,-47,49]
C=[[2,-1,5,1],[3,2,2,-6],[1,3,3,-1],[5,-2,-3,3]]
X=[]
for i in range(0,len(B)):
    for j in range(0,len(B)):
        C[j][i]=B[j]
        if i>0:
            C[j][i-1]=A[j][i-1]
    X.append(round(linalg.det(C)/linalg.det(A),1))
 
print('w=%s'%X[0],'x=%s'%X[1],'y=%s'%X[2],'z=%s'%X[3])
```

Comment: With python 3.7.3 it gives the result w=2.0 x=-12.0 y=-4.0 z=1.0. What is the error you are encounting?

Comment: I want to use `np.matrix` and this code is not working if I typecast the `list` as `np.matrix`

Comment: okay sorry, I made it work, I did some calculations error

Comment: can you make it work for `np.matrix`, right now I am using this code by implementing the matrices as `np.array`

Comment: You could convert your ABC np.matrix to np.array and it will work. Use: A=A.getA()
B=B.getA()[0]
C=C.getA() You did not implement your matrixes as np.array. You have np.matrix. However, calling getA() on the np.matrix will return the np.array variant of it.